# Is $x^2 = y ^2$ an immersed submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

So, I know that this isn't an embedded submanifold, since with the subspace topology inherited from $\mathbb{R}^2$, it is not locally Euclidean at $0$. Further, I also know that if I can parametrize it nicely, I will be able to say that it is the image of an injective smooth immersion and thus an immersed submanifold, but I can't seem to do that and don't know how to prove that it is not one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If "immersed submanifold" means "the image of an immersion, a map whose differential is injective everywhere", then the crossed lines are the image of two parallel lines under a simple map.

More explicitly, let's define a map from $X=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|y^2=1\}$ to $Y=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|x^2=y^2\}$ via $f(x,y) = (x,\text{sign}(y)x).$ It maps two parallel lines to your two crossed lines. Since $\text{sign}(y)$ is constant on the connected components, its non-differentiability at $y=0$ doesn't come up. So $f$ is differentiable, and is an immersion.

However as Jack Lee points out in the comments, the more usual definition of "immersed submanifold" is a subset with its own topology and smooth structure (not necessarily subspace) such that the inclusion is an immersion.

We can realize $Y$ as an immersed submanifold in this sense as well. Let's define $f,g,h\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ by $f(x)=(x,x)$, and $g(x) = (-e^x,e^x)$ and $h(x)=(e^x,-e^x).$ So $f$ parametrizes the line through the origin and quadrants III and I, $g$ parametrizes the ray through quadrant II (approaching but never reaching the origin), and $h$ parametrizes the ray through quadrant IV (also approaching but never reaching the origin). These functions define a topology on their image which is not the subspace topology. Consider for example that the space with its immersed topology has three connected components, while it has only one in the subspace topology. They give the set $Y=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|x^2=y^2\}$ the structure of an immersed submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: It seems the definition of "immersed submanifold" the OP is using (which is also the one I use in my book _Intro to Smooth Manifolds_) does not allow "self-crossings," because he/she wanted to show that the set is the image of an _injective_ smooth immersion. If so, this solution doesn't work because $f$ is not injective. But you can easily modify it to be injective by deleting one point from the domain, say $(0,-1)$.

Comment: @JackLee ok if I delete the origin, then I have produced an injective immersion according to this stricter definition. But how do we show that $\{x^2=y^2\}$ is _not_ such an object?

Comment: The set $\{x^2 = y^2\}$ definitely _is_ an immersed submanifold, if you give it an appropriate topology (not the subspace topology) and smooth structure, because it's the image of an injective immersion. (See Proposition 5.18 in my book.) It's just not an embedded submanifold.

Comment: @JackLee Is that also lemma 8.18 in the first edition? Anyway, I've understood your correction now. With the right topology, the self-crossing may be of the form of the infinite tail of a line approaching its midpoint. Let me edit my answer to make this distinction clearer.

Comment: If we delete the point $(0, -1)$ from $\{ y^2 = 1\}$, don't we lose continuity?

Comment: @ziggurism: No, the analogous result in the first edition is Proposition 8.16.

Comment: @DeepishaSolanki I deleted my previous comment because I had failed to notice you were talking about the two parallel lines, rather than the crossed lines. That point is in the set. However i still don’t see what you mean about losing continuity. A restriction of a continuous function to any subspace is still continuous.

Comment: @JackLee PS Jack I’m a former student of your book, and a big fan. I hope you won’t take it personally that I forgot the definition of an immersed submanifold.

Comment: @ziggurism, I see what you're saying now, the continuity would not be affected.